# constexpr with untouched non-constexpr arguments: Who is correct, clang or gcc?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, constexpr

I have 4 test cases and I believe that all of them are valid:

```
constexpr int f(int const& /*unused*/){
    return 1;
}

void g(int const& p){
    constexpr int a = f(p); // clang error, gcc valid

    int v = 0;
    constexpr int b = f(v); // clang valid, gcc valid

    int const& r = v;
    constexpr int c = f(r); // clang error, gcc error

    int n = p;
    constexpr int d = f(n); // clang valid, gcc valid
}

int main(){
    int p = 0;
    g(p);
}
```

Clang and GCC differ only in the first test case.

I tested with clang 4 & 5 (20170319) and with GCC 7.0.1 (20170221).

If I'm right it would massively simplify the usage of boost::hana in static_assert's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[[expr.const]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.const#2):

> An expression `e` is a *core constant expression* unless the
>   evaluation of `e`, following the rules of the abstract machine, would
>   evaluate one of the following expressions:
>
> - [...]
> - an *id-expression* that refers to a variable or data member of reference type unless the reference has a preceding initialization and
>     either
>
>   - it is initialized with a constant expression or
>   - its lifetime began within the evaluation of `e`;
> - [...]

Neither condition is satisfied for `p` or `r`. Therefore neither `f(p)` nor `f(r)` is a core constant expression and hence neither can be used to initialize a `constexpr` variable. Clang is correct.