# using result of constexpr function as a template parameter (clang vs gcc)

Tags: c++, templates, clang, constexpr

Please take a look at the code below, sorry that is a bit lengthy, but I did my best to reproduce the problem with a minimum example (there is also a [live copy](http://ideone.com/7MJOSA) of it). There I basically have a metafunction which returns the size of string literal, and constexpr function which wraps it.  Then when I call those functions in a template parameter gcc (5.4, 6.2) is happy with it, but clang (3.8, 3.9) barfs with "non-type template argument is not a constant expression" in test body on `strsize(s)`. If I replace with a `str_size<S>` both compilers are happy. So the questions are:

1. whether that is a problem with clang, or my code?
2. What is the way to make it compile on both clang and gcc with constexpr function?

   ```
   template<size_t N> using string_literal_t = char[N];

   template<class T> struct StrSize; ///< metafunction to get the size of string literal alikes 

   /// specialize StrSize for string literals
   template<size_t N>
   struct StrSize <string_literal_t<N>>{ static constexpr size_t value = N-1; };

   /// template variable, just for convenience
   template <class T>
   constexpr size_t str_size = StrSize<T>::value;

   /// now do the same but with constexpr function
   template<class T>
   constexpr auto strsize(const T&) noexcept-> decltype(str_size<T>) {
      return str_size<T>;
   }

   template<class S, size_t... Is>
   constexpr auto test_helper(const S& s, index_sequence<Is...>) noexcept-> array<char, str_size<S>> {
      return {s[Is]...};
   }

   template<class S>
   constexpr auto test(const S& s) noexcept-> decltype(auto) {
   // return test_helper(s, make_index_sequence<str_size<S>>{}); // this work in both clang and gcc
      return test_helper(s, make_index_sequence<strsize(s)>{});  // this works only in gcc
   }

   auto main(int argc, char *argv[])-> int {
      static_assert(strsize("qwe") == 3, "");
      static_assert(noexcept(test("qwe")) == true, "");

      return 0;
   }
   ```

Comment: What's wrong with using `str_size<S1>` instead of `strsize(s1)`?

Comment: @max66 In this particular example nothing is wrong with that. But it can only work with classes parametrized with size, if the size is the state and not part of the type I need to call the function on object, not on a type. Probably if I do not find another way I will use sfinae to distinguish types coming into test3, but I do not like that idea.

Comment: I ran into same problem as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42997847/ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clang is correct here. The problem is in the code and in GCC, which erroneously accepted it. This was fixed in GCC 10: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66477

According to the standard [expr.const#5.12](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.const#5.12):

> An expression E is a core constant expression unless the evaluation of E, following the rules of the abstract machine, would evaluate one of the following:
> ...
> an id-expression that refers to a variable or data member of reference type unless the reference has a preceding initialization and either
>
> - it is usable in constant expressions or
> - its lifetime began within the evaluation of E;
>   And here the compiler is unable to verify the validity of reference in `test(const S& s)`.

Actually there is a nice article to read here: https://brevzin.github.io/c++/2020/02/05/constexpr-array-size/

As to your other question:

> What is the way to make it compile on both clang and gcc with constexpr function?

You can replace references with `std::array` passed by value:

```
#include <array>
using namespace std;

template<class T> struct StrSize;

template<size_t N>
struct StrSize <array<char,N>>{ static constexpr size_t value = N-1; };

template <class T>
constexpr size_t str_size = StrSize<T>::value;

template<class T>
constexpr auto strsize(const T&) noexcept-> decltype(str_size<T>) {
   return str_size<T>;
}

template<class S, size_t... Is>
constexpr auto test_helper(const S& s, index_sequence<Is...>) noexcept-> array<char, str_size<S>> {
   return {s[Is]...};
}

constexpr auto test(array<char,4> s) noexcept-> decltype(auto) {
   return test_helper(s, make_index_sequence<strsize(s)>{});
}

int main() {
   static_assert(noexcept(test({"qwe"})) == true, "");
}
```

Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/G8zof38b1